# How to animate object with clothes to prevent cropping

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have my dog model and jersey on it. Dog's mesh under the jersey is deleted. I have done rigging with rigify, and now intend to do the galloping animation. Problem is on the front legs, where the scalpula is and the jersey. What could be best way to prevent cropping. Additional rig for jersey, to put it around sleeve, and how to combine my custom rig and rigify?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Radoon, small hint: don't ask "what's the best way..." because these type of questions will be closed due to "opioned based" question - that's a rule of this site.

Comment: from your third picture it looks like the body and the cloth don't seem to have the same weight?

Comment: @Chris yeah, thanks. however that's what first comes in mind since there is a lot of ways of solving problem :D gonna start using something like how to

Comment: @moonboots it does not, however when I try to paint all red it still pops out. Thought maybe about driver bones or something like that. Gonna upload just leg as .blend file so you can check if you can.

Comment: it may still pop out if another bone influence the cloth and not the body or vice versa, but have you tried to reparent With Automatic Weights?

Comment: I uploaded just leg since I am not allowed to share whole mesh, I hope it's enough

Comment: I tried automatic weighting but it doesn't catch the jersey. I could do it manually with painting, but it crops